# Java: Is (int) double reliable?

Tags: java, math, double

When I perform simple math in java with doubles and other number data types, the double values seem to randomly vary a bit from the supposed result, which might be 5,59999999997 or 6,0000000002 or something. When I cast to int, the double value is obviously rounded down to the next whole number. Does this mean the double could be both 5 or 6? Or does that "5,999999999997" still count as 6 though which would be depending on the binary float value? If not, is there a way to let the negative vary be rounded up, but not lower values from 5,5 to 5,999999999996?

- I mean, I dont really want to round the value as described in my last sentence. I'd like to always round down to the next whole number, but I don't want to cause an extra decrement due to wrong double math results.

Comment: Yes, double is an approximation; (unfortunately) BigDecimal is needed for errorless calculations like in financial software.

Comment: @JoopEggen Unless you use rounding ;)

Answer (score 4):

Converting a double to an int always rounds down. You can round to the nearest whole integer via [Math.round(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29). The double is varying from what you expect because of [floating point error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_error#Accuracy_problems).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round, you can use the round() method.

```
 double d = 6 +/- some small error
 long l = Math.round(d);
```

Or you can add 0.5 for positive numbers

```
 long l = (long) (d + 0.5);
```

or

```
 long l = (long) (d + (d < 0 ? -0.5 : 0.5));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Usually when you cast a double to int you add 0.5 to have a nice round.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Language Specification:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4)

> The Java programming language uses round toward zero when converting a floating value to an
>   integer (§5.1.3), which acts, in this case, as though the number were truncated, discarding
>   the mantissa bits. Rounding toward zero chooses at its result the format's value closest to
>   and no greater in magnitude than the infinitely precise result.

So 5,999999999997 when casted to an int will 5 and 6,0000000002 will be 6. If I understand what you are asking with having negative versions of the values (e.g. -5.97), I fail to see how
`Math.round()` does not suffice you. -6,0000000002 will be rounded to -6 as will -5,999999999997 and every other value above (but not including) -5.5.